# Макрос для проверки возвращаемого значения

Tags: c, макросы, обработка-ошибок, препроцессор, rvalue

Хочу написать макрос для семейства функций `pthread_*`,
который бы сравнивал результат функции с нулём, 
и если значение отлично от нуля вызывал бы мою функцию, передавая в неё это значение
Макрос должен быть постфиксным, т. е. должен идти после вызова функции:

```
pthread_create() MY_MACRO;
```

где `MY_MACRO` разворачивается в что-то подобное

```
my_func(/*результат pthread_create()*/);
```

Варианты типа

```
MY_MACRO pthread_create();
```

и

```
MY_MACRO(pthread_create());
```

не рассматриваются по эстетическим причинам

Comment: Как вы предполагаете, что остальные Сишники будут думать об авторе подбного кода?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Если кому-то вдруг понадобится что-то подобное...
Можно воспользоваться магией ассемблера: положить в заранее созданную переменную значение регистра, в котором хранится результат функции

```
#define MY_MACRO ; asm("mov %%eax, %0" : "=r" (result)); result != 0 ? my_func(result) : 0;
```

Естественно, данное решение имеет спорную переносимость между разными архитектурами процессоров

**Update:**

Вспомнил про замечательное свойство индексирования массивов, а именно, что `arr[idx]` раскрывается в что-то похожее
на `*((arr)+(idx))`, что позволяет обращаться к элементу массива таким образом: `idx[arr]`. 
Этим я воспользовался:

```
#define MAX_ERRNUM 256
static __thread char errnum_array[MAX_ERRNUM];

#define MY_MACRO [errnum_array] = 1; my_func(__FILE__, __LINE__);

static void my_func(char* filename, int line)
{
  int errnum = -1;

  //0-th element means success
  for(int i = 1; i < MAX_ERRNUM; i++)
  {
    if(errnum_array[i] == 1)
    {
      errnum = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(errnum == -1)
  {
    /*this means that we indexed an array element
    out of its bounds - memory corruption occured*/
    if(errnum_array[0] != 1)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "<%s>,  line %d: Improper use of a macro: memory corruption detected\n", filename, line);
      abort();
    }

    errnum_array[0] = 0;
  }
  else
      /*error handling*/
}
```

Comment: Непереносимо даже для разных компиляторов.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать воспользоваться сокращенными вычислениями логических операторов...

Если `pthread_create()` возвращает 0, то d

```
pthread_create() && my_func()
```

`my_func()` вычисляться не будет. А если не 0 - будет. Т.е. что-то [типа](https://ideone.com/sgERVO)

```
#define MY_MACRO && my_func()
```

Вот с передачей значения туго, раз вы такой эстет... разве что повторяйте вызов, раз она с ошибкой - то и второй раз ошибется :) -

```
#define MY_MACRO && my_func(pthread_create())
```

Answer (score 1):

Макросы можно использовать, чтобы сделать свой вариант функции а-ля пространство имён.

```
# define pthread_create_NameSpace(P,T,F,A,W) { \
    int _e = pthread_create((P),(T),(F),(A)); \
    if ( _e ) { \
      W; } }
```

Вход в пространство имён :

```
# define pthread_create pthread_create_NameSpace
pthread_create ( & p , NULL , & func , NULL , printf ("_e=%d\n" , _e ) ; );
# undef pthread_create
```

и выход.

Comment: Интересное предложение, но не хотелось бы баловаться с "обёртками". К тому же, если идти таким путём то для каждой функции придётся делать свой вариант макроса